# Magento custom options 'required' error

Tags: magento, magento-1.6, configurable-product

thanks in advance to any help that anyone is able to offer.
When a custom option field in magento is set to 'required' it does not add to cart and asks user to select option. However when I uncheck the required option in admin in then works. I think this issue maybe affecting config products so I would like to find a solution other than not use the required option.

Using Magento 1.6

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could create you own validation

The Add to cart button trigger productAddToCartForm.submit(this)

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

Then you could rewrite your own productAddToCartForm.submit()

```
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {

    // do your custom validation here  
    // eg. if (this.validator.validate() && customValidate())
    if (this.validator.validate()) {

            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
               form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
   }        
   else{
       productOptionError();
   }
}.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```